# What can I do in qgis to manage a WMS frequently unreachable?

Tags: qgis, wms, network

In my project I have a layer linked to an external WMS server (provided by a local institution). The problem is that it is somewhat unreliable: it is down rather often.

Is there something I can do to correctly manage this situation?

At the moment it simply removes the layer, so if I were to save the project I should re-add the WMS later (when it is back on, unpredictable).

A far better behaviour would be just ignoring it and show some kind of warning when trying to get data out of it

Comment: DO you want the maps just to be there all the time or keep connectivity to the map.

Comment: It's not necessary for me to always have a local copy of the images, I seldom need this WMS

Comment: so it is to try and maintain a stable connection to it.  Well in that case i cant help.